# Set on action for pawns

Tags: java, javafx

I got several objects of pawns in my checkers game. I want to be able to make a set on action on every one of them (circles) without making 24 different set on actions for every pawn. Got any ideas?

Comment: Use a loop and store the checkers in an array?

Comment: "without making 24 different set on actions for every pawn". Why not? Just call `setOnAction` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Get all pawns in parent node using getChildren() method and store it in list then iterate it and call setOnAction as below way.

```
List<Node> chieldNode = new ArrayList<>();
        chieldNode = parentNode.getChildren();
    for (Node node : chieldNode) {
        if (node instanceof Button) {
           ((Button) node).setOnAction(e -> {
                System.out.println(((Button) node).getText());
            });
       }
}
```

Or refer below example to get some idea

```
public class DemoEx extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
                GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
                Button[] button = new Button[100];
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                        button[j] = new Button(i + "" + j);
                        button[j].setPrefSize(50, 50);
                        gridPane.add(button[j], i, j);
                    }
                }

                List<Node> chieldNode = new ArrayList<>();
                chieldNode = gridPane.getChildren();
                for (Node node : chieldNode) {
                    if (node instanceof Button) {
                        ((Button) node).setOnAction(e -> {
                            System.out.println(((Button) node).getText());
                        });
                    }
                }

                Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, gridPane.getMaxHeight(), gridPane.getMaxWidth());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```